# Why is my program not generating two graphs at once? I want both graphs to appear within the plot explorer at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

With this program my goal was to import the two given files with panda and use that data to create two separate graphs. I was able to create the graphs and save them in different documents but my assignment calls for creating them at the same time and displaying them in the same window. How would I adjust my code to make that work? I suspect I have an issue with the file_name portion of the code and that preventing both portions of code from running properly but I'm not sure or it could be the subplot portion.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import interactive
import numpy as np


def main(file_name):
    file_name = r"College Enrollments.csv"
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    department = df['Department']
    enrollment_count = df[' Enrollment count']
    
    
    
    plt.figure(figsize= (9,3))
    plt.subplot(131)
    plt.bar(department,enrollment_count)
    plt.title('College Enrollments')
    plt.show
    x_axis = 'Department'
    y_axis = 'Enrollment count'
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0,4001,500))
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)

    file_name = r"CS Faculty.csv"
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    professor = df['CS Professor']
    yoe = df['Years of Experience']
    #end of graph 1
    
    
    plt.figure(figsize= (9,3))
    plt.subplot(132)
    plt.bar(professor,yoe)
    plt.title('CS Faculty')
    plt.show
    x_axis = 'CS Professor'
    y_axis = 'Years of Experience'
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0,31,5))
    plt.xticks(rotation = 90)

    
   # read the file_name into a pandas dataframe
    
    # plot the dataframe using arguments "title", "legend", "x", "y", "kind" and "color"

    # The only four statements that may use the matplotlib library appear next.
    # Do not modify them.
    plt.xlabel(x_axis)      # Note: x-axis should be determined above
    plt.ylabel(y_axis)      # Note: y-axis should be determined above
    interactive(True)       # This allows multiple figures to be displayed simultaneously
    plt.show()
#end of graph 2
# -------------------------------------------------

main("College Enrollments.csv")
main("CS Faculty.csv")
```

Comment: You should call `plt.show()` only once, at the end. And also `plt.figure(...)` only once, at the beginning.

Comment: What is the point in defining a function with parameter if you overwrite the parameter inside it and actually loop over several values?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to write a function for this but your looking for something like :

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.suptitle('Horizontally stacked subplots')
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot(x, -y)
```

The best thing to get used to is looking at documentation, you will be spending A LOT of time reading documentation if you plan on coding anything.
You can find everything you need here: https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html